# When I try to use secpol.msc (Group Policy) I get an error

Tags: windows, group-policy

When I try to use secpol.msc (Group Policy) I get an error:

> Failed to open group policy object on
>   this computer. You may not have
>   appropriate rights.

I am an admin and I tried running it as a administrator but I still get it.

Comment: Is your account part of a domain? If yes, try assigning it a Domain Administrator Role (Adding it to a domain administrator group).

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @AndrewCooper i have win7 ultimate

Comment: @Thomas no I am not on a domain

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the permissions on the Group Policy files are wrong. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32` and open the properties of the (hidden) `GroupPolicy` folder. Go to the Security tab. The correct permissions are *Full control* for Administrators and `SYSTEM`; Authenticated Users should have *Read & execute*, *List folder contents*, and *Read*. If the ACLs aren't right, open the advanced security settings and click *Change permissions*. Adjust the permission entries appropriately, check *Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object*, and click OK.

[image: correct settings]

If that doesn't help, you'll need to look at the security on `GroupPolicyUsers`. That folder has the same settings on the folder itself, but do not replace all child object permissions! It has (hidden) subfolders, each named with the SID of the user it applies to. On each user policy folder, Administrators and `SYSTEM` must have *Full control*, but the user (not Authenticated Users) should have *Read & execute*, *List folder contents*, and *Read*. Those permissions should be inherited by the children of the per-user folders.

Finally, if none of that helps, check the permissions on `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`. They should be the following:

- `TrustedInstaller` has *Full control* on the folder and subfolders (not files)
- `SYSTEM` has *Modify* on the folder itself, but *Full control* on subfolders and files
- Administrators have *Modify* on the folder itself, but *Full control* on subfolders and files
- Users have *Read & execute*, on the folder and everything in it
- `CREATOR OWNER` has *Full control* on subfolders and files only
- `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` have *Read & execute* on the folder and everything in it

[image: correct PolicyDefinitions ACL]